# issue in droppable area jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

this is my droppable div

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="f_img ui-draggable ui-droppable" id="f_img1" data-type="swap" data-is-empty="yes"> 
<img src="http://localhost/Gaelsoft//assets/images/tshirt.png" style="cursor:pointer;">
</div>
```

and this looks like this [image]

div has red border and image is inserted using img tag.

```
<div class="f_img"></div>
```

is droppable.

now what happens
drop is working fine when i drag my object to left of the image, but do not work when i drag over img and right to the img.

can any one help me??

Comment: Show the code what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add tollerance : "pointer"

now Mouse pointer overlaps the droppable. and you will be able to drop your object any where in draggable area.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  tolerance: "fit"
});
```